# index assignment to a variable

Tags: python-3.x, string, variables, indexing

I am new to programming and recently started learning strings and loops. I want to know is it possible to assign the index of *any alphabet from a string* to *a variable*?

```
def max_char(a_string):
val="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
counter=0
for i in range (len(val)):
   for k in range(len(a_string)):
      if val[i] == a_string[k]:
        if counter==0:
         x1=val.index(i)  #here I want to assign the index of ith element of val to x1. Also tried *x1=val[i].index*
         counter=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign to i

```
def max_char(a_string):
    val = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(val)):
        for k in range(len(a_string)):
            if val[i] == a_string[k]:
                if counter == 0:
                    x1 = i  # here I want to assign the index of ith element of val to x1. Also tried *x1=val[i].index*
                    counter = 1
                    print(x1)


max_char("s")
Output: 18
```

Answer (score 1):

you can assign it by using the index itself that you are declaring in the loop.

```
x1=i #This is the index of val in that iteration.
```

In this case this code will return the first element of *a_string* that is also in *val*.